# Are humans the only primates being engaged in group sex?

Tags: human-biology, mammals, sex

There are quite many examples of humans being involved in group sex. I won't say it is a common thing and won't say whether it is "natural" or "cultural" (but "cultural" only means induced to majority by minority).

What I'm asking is if there are any other primates being involved in group sex (or how is it called in biology?). Under "group sex" I mean a sexual intercourse where several males or females can see other males and females being involved in sex too, right as they themselves are.

Comment: I haven't looked this up specifically, but bonobo's are sort of literally crazed sex monkeys - I'd be surprised if they don't do this.

Comment: @Nicolai Their sex has 13 seconds duration. I'm not sure another male or female has time even to come there.